# Solr in Docker container unable to work with persistent data store

Tags: docker, docker-compose, solr

I have a Solr backend which I want to work with a Flask frontend. I'm planning to run both in Docker using `docker-compose`.

The relevant part of my `docker-compose.yml` looks like this:

```
version: '3'

services:

  solr:
    image: solr
    ports:
     - "8983:8983"
    volumes:
      - ./data:/var/solr/
    entrypoint:
    - bash
    - "-c"
    - "precreate-core stable; precreate-core unstable; precreate-core archive; exec solr -f"

[...]

volumes:
  data:
```

It creates on the host a persistent `./data` directory, which is mounted on the guest to `/var/solr`. However, when I try to run it:

```
pc% docker-compose up              
[+] Running 2/0
 ⠿ Container src-solr-1      Recreated
 ⠿ Container src-frontend-1  Recreated
Attaching to src-frontend-1, src-solr-1
src-solr-1      | Executing /opt/solr/docker/scripts/precreate-core stable
src-solr-1      | cp: cannot create directory '/var/solr/data/stable': No such file or directory
src-solr-1      | Executing /opt/solr/docker/scripts/precreate-core unstable
src-solr-1      | Executing /opt/solr/docker/scripts/precreate-core archive
src-solr-1      | cp: cannot create directory '/var/solr/data/unstable': No such file or directory
src-solr-1      | cp: cannot create directory '/var/solr/data/archive': No such file or directory
src-solr-1      | 
src-solr-1      | Solr home directory /var/solr/data not found!
src-solr-1      | 
src-solr-1 exited with code 1
src-frontend-1 exited with code 0
```

The `./data` folder remains empty.

I've already `chown`ed it to `8983:8983`, so it shouldn't be a permissions issue.

Comment: Isn't it complaining about `data` missing inside `/var/solr` and not `/var/solr` missing? So you'd possibly need to create a `data` directory inside your `data` directory first?

Comment: @MatsLindh yes, you're right. I didn't expect to have to create those directories manually. Do you mind if I add this as an answer to mark the question as solved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is complaining the `data` directory missing inside /var/solr - and not /var/solr itself missing. You'll have to create the `/data` directory first, then let the cores be created inside that directory.

Answer (score 0):

I have started container with `docker run` and my problem was that there was no error output

```
docker run -d -v "./solrdata:/var/solr" -p 8983:8983 --name my_solr solr solr-precreate gettingstarted
```

I could tell it was failing because in `docker ps -a` STATUS was exiting right away. `docker logs` was helpful to see an error

```
docker logs my_solr
Cannot write to /var/solr as 8983:8983
drwxr-xr-x. 1 1000 1000 0 Feb 20 01:57 /var/solr
```

Then, this would fix

```
sudo chown 8983:8983 solrdata/
```

Not exactly the same issue, just saying logs help.